# 2D array with for loop and in range in python

Tags: python, arrays

I have this two sets of code, i assume both should have equal output but they dont. Can someone tell what is going through both code? Any insight is much appreciated.
Set 1

```
x = [[1],[1],[1],[1],[1]]
for i in x:
    print(i)

x[1][0]=99
print(x[1][0])
for i in x:
    print(i)
```

The output for set1 is

```
[1]
[1]
[1]
[1]
[1]
99
[1]
[99]
[1]
[1]
[1]
```

Set2

```
y = [1]
x = []

for i in range(5):
    x.append(y)
for i in x:
    print(i)

x[1][0]=99
print(x[1][0])
for i in x:
    print(i)
```

The output for set2 is

```
[1]
[1]
[1]
[1]
[1]
99
[99]
[99]
[99]
[99]
[99]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read about [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You can also use [Python-Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) which helps to visualize the execution of the code step-by-step.

Comment: `x.append(y)` **keeps appending the same list**. You need to explicitly *copy* the object if you want a copy

Comment: Probably would be helpful to read: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 0):

In the second set, when you do `x.append(y)` you append a reference of `y` to `x`. Thus all changes to the original or any reference of it will be applied to all references.

This is why when you assign a different value at `x[1][0]=99` all of the `y` references get change.

You can read more at: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pass-by-reference-vs-value-in-python/

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand `references` in python.

```py
y = [1]
x = []

for i in range(5):
    x.append(y)
```

This part of your code will fill the list `x` with **references** to the `y` variable, you could imagine it being

```py
>>> x
>>> [y, y, y, y, y]
```

So further in your code, when you do

```py
x[1][0]=99
```

You are indeed editing the `y` variable! So now:

```py
>>> y
>>> [99]

>>> x
# As stated before, it's like [y, y, y, y, y]
>>> [99, 99, 99, 99, 99]
```

Here's why your code isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Because it's by reference. In the second set you are essentially changing y. So all values in x changes.